# using merge statement in ssis package

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, azure-sql-database, ssis

Here is my situation.

I have got Table A in database DB1(sql server) and Table B in database DB2(sql azure) with same table structure. I need to compare the data in table A and Table B and add the missed records in Table B and also update table B.

Can anyone help me on how to do this in a SSIS Package using merge statement?

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to write the merge statment in t-sql, just use an Execute SQL statement to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the same type of question which i also asked earlier:

[Merge two Table in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495786/merge-two-table-in-sql-server-2008)

In your case write the fully qualified name of table means
SERVERNAME.DBNAME.TABLENAME in this way.

Hope this help.:)