# SQL insert not executing if data already present

Tags: sql, insert, sql-update

```
IF (EXISTS
  (SELECT documentsRepo.DocumentRouteNumber
   FROM documentsRepo
   INNER JOIN dreDocuments ON documentsRepo.DocumentRouteNumber = dreDocuments.DocumentRouteNumber))
UPDATE DocumentsRepo
SET documentsRepo.documentTypeID = dreDocuments.DocumentTypeID,
documentsRepo.DepartmentID = dreDocuments.DepartmentID
FROM documentsRepo
INNER JOIN dreDocuments ON documentsRepo.DocumentRouteNumber = dreDocuments.DocumentRouteNumber ELSE
INSERT INTO documentsRepo (DocumentTypeID, DepartmentID, DocumentRouteNumber, SOURCE, Destination)
SELECT DocumentTypeID,
   DepartmentID,
   DocumentRouteNumber,
   SOURCE,
   Destination
FROM dreDocuments
```

I am using the above code to update or insert records. It works properly in the first record insert. Update works perfectly. But next insert batch doesn't work.

Comment: You can achive simillar functionality through `merge` also. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495786/merge-two-table-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: Do you get any error?

Answer (score 1):

You can use MERGE or try to use following code:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
UPDATE DocumentsRepo SET .... ; 
IF(@@Rowcount=0)
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO DocumentsRepo .....;
END
```